# Is the product of ideals in an algebra an ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Yesterday, my professor made the following claim:

Let $K$ be a field, and let $L$ be a $K$-algebra, with ideals $A,B$. Then
$$AB = \left\{ \sum_i a_i b_i : a_i \in A, b_i \in B\right\} $$
is an ideal of $L$.

Myself and another student have tried to prove this, but we can't get anywhere without assuming that multiplication in $L$ is associative. I know that this claim is true in the context of Lie algebras, but the proof involves the Jacobi identity, which a general $K$-algebra does not have. Is this claim simply false without assuming associativity?

Comment: I would define $AB$ as the smallest ideal containing $\{ab\mid a\in A,\ b\in B\}$. Then in the case of associative algebras, one could show that it is equal to $\{\sum_ia_ib_i\mid a_i\in A,\ b_i\in B\}$.

Comment: It seems like you can't show $(ab)r\in AB$ without associativity (or a replacement for it, like the Jacobi identity.) Are you *sure* the intention was for you to consider all manner of nonassociative algebras in general?!

Comment: @rschwieb I am sure that my professor claimed what I stated. We spoke again in class today, and he said that he was willing to believe it was false, as he had drawn it from a source that didn't cover algebras in as much generality as he did in class. So he probably just didn't look carefully enough at hypotheses for that lemma.

Comment: @JoshuaRuiter Sounds about right!

Comment: Seems like a ring theory class. Usually in that context K-algebra with K a field should mean a ring L with a homomorphism $K\to L$ no?